# Authentication to host user failed - Using Password NO - VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am encountering an error where it is stating:

```
authentication to host '' for user '' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: no)
```

Now I read online about checking my passwords, my connection strings, and IP address. I have checked them all. I even checked the user privileges on my database and I have all access and every ability to modify, delete, update, and insert the database.

What is weird is that, it is only this set of code that it will not execute (This code should run when I add a new record):

```
Private Sub PolicyEnableFields()
    'Automate Last Modified By textbox
    Dim sqlAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim sqlTable As New DataTable

    Dim sqlText As String = "select full_name from user_privileges where user_name='" & Login.UserIDTextBox.Text & "'"

    With sqlCommand
        .CommandText = sqlText
        .Connection = sConnection
    End With

    With sqlAdapter
        .SelectCommand = sqlCommand
        .Fill(sqlTable)
    End With

    For i = 0 To sqlTable.Rows.Count - 1
        Me.PolicyModifiedTextBox.Text = (sqlTable.Rows(i)("full_name"))

    Next
    sqlTable.Dispose()
    sqlCommand.Dispose()
    sqlAdapter.Dispose()
End Sub
```

But when I run the exact some piece of code in a different SUB it works perfectly fine (This code runs when I edit a existing record):

```
 Private Sub PolicyEditButton_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PolicyEditButton.Click
    'Automate Last Modified By textbox
    Dim sqlAdapter As New MySqlDataAdapter
    Dim sqlCommand As New MySqlCommand
    Dim sqlTable As New DataTable

    Dim sqlText As String = "select full_name from user_privileges where user_name='" & Login.UserIDTextBox.Text & "'"

    With sqlCommand
        .CommandText = sqlText
        .Connection = sConnection
    End With

    With sqlAdapter
        .SelectCommand = sqlCommand
        .Fill(sqlTable)
    End With

    For i = 0 To sqlTable.Rows.Count - 1
        Me.PolicyModifiedTextBox.Text = (sqlTable.Rows(i)("full_name"))

    Next
    sqlTable.Dispose()
    sqlCommand.Dispose()
    sqlAdapter.Dispose()
End Sub
```

HERE is my connection STRING (of course I will not show my PW):

```
Public sqlConnect As String = "server=10.0.7.30; userid=Alliance; password=*******; database=mydb; convert zero datetime=True"
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `sConnection`, and make sure it is initialized with the proper connection string. The error message mentions localhost, but the connection string you show is 10.0.7.30.